# How to style a Next Image tag inside a figure tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I am trying to optimize my website with Next's native `Image` tag. However, I am struggling to set variable heights on the images. Since the images can have different height, i'm not sure how that works with Next Image.

### The problem

How to set variable heights on each image coming in from an API?

### Initial Approach

Without using Next/Image, I am able to achieve the result of a a grid like structure with jagged image heights.

```js
<figure key={index} className="break-inside-avoid-column">
  <img src={img.url} alt={img.altText} />
  <figcaption>
    {img.altText}
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

This is what displays in the browser and the effect I am trying to convert to with Next image:

[image]

### New Approach

After swapping out the old `img` tag to `Image`, this is what I have come up with. Everything works, but the variable heights of each image are all set to the same height. My goal is to have the heights of image be variable, only the widths should be the same.

```js
<figure
  key={index}
  className="block mb-10 text-center break-inside-avoid-column">
  <Image
    layout="responsive"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    className="object-cover rounded-xl"
    src={img.url}
    alt={img.altText}
  />
  <figcaption className="z-10 mt-4 text-sm italic text-gray-600">
    {img.altText}
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is the result of using the `Image` tag in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Could you create a *runnable* [mcve]? (codesandbox.io or similar).

Comment: @SeanW Next.js requires a height and width attribute https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#width

Comment: Have you tried setting the height and width to the original image's height and width? I think `layout="responsive"` takes care of the scaling for you.

Comment: @SeanW The thing with that is that the images can be different aspect ratio. If I were to explicitly set the width or height, then all the images would scale the same. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Each image should have it's own height and width.  Each image will be as wide as the column but won't be the same height.